# How can I create an owner lookup field similar to change owner on any record

Tags: lookup, user-record

We have a request for a field to show a referral from internal sales users. I thought rather than a picklist that we would have to constantly manage, maybe there was a way to use the built in user object with a lookup of some kind.
Does anyone have any suggestion please?

mlr.

Comment: Do you want a lookup field to the User record or a lookup on the User record to any SObject?

Comment: I'm not sure, I would think the user record. I don't even know where to begin with a lookup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a new custom field on each of the objects you would like the User Lookup to appear on.

1. Create a field with the type Lookup
   [image: Field Type]
2. Choose the related object "User" from the drop down
   [image: Relationship]
3. Enter the Label and ID for the field. 
   [image: Detail]

Comment: No problem, you can take it even further and add a filter to the lookup if the user should only be someone with a particular role or profile using the lookup filters.

Comment: thanks, that makes sense, and good to know for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Question: The records will have one referral or multiple referrals? If one, then you can definitely create a user lookup field on the object.

Comment: Yes just one referral. I don't know where to begin as far as making a user lookup field.